# Forward mouseevent to canvas under element - particles.js mouse detection

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, particles.js

I want to use particle.js (https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) on my website as a background. I configured it to detect the mouse on the canvas but if I start adding other html elements, the mouse detection stops working. I found a website (http://demo.diviwebdesign.com/fullwidth-header-extended-demo-1-json/) which apparently gets around this issue but I have no idea how they did it. Do you have a idea?

If I use detection on window level, as soon as I scroll or if the canvas does not fill the whole window, the detected mouse location is off so thats not a suitable solution either. I would need a way to forward the mouse through the obscuring element down to the canvas.

Comment: try this one https://codepen.io/filipemcribeiro/pen/Wwvrbj

Comment: Interesting. So that first effect is not using particles.js but something different? Where did you get this one from? Is this also a library for particle effects?

Comment: yes, its another library. Here is the link .... https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/09/23/animated-background-headers/